# How to use localstack as S3 in Magento 2 in development env?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to mock S3 on my local machine, for which I have used localstack. I am using localstack via docker image, which is running successfully on my local machine.

I have followed below URL to setup localstack in my system:

https://onexlab-io.medium.com/localstack-s3-e28ad393c09

I can create S3 bucket and upload and list files from my local machine after setup.

But how to use localstack in Magento 2 in development env. After setting up Magento and localstack whenever I am trying to enable remote storage via below command:

```
bin/magento setup:config:set --remote-storage-driver aws-s3 --remote-storage-bucket m242_bucket --remote-storage-region us-east-1
```

it is returning with below error message:

```
Adapter error: Unable to write file at location: storage.flag. In ConfigSetCommand.php line 151:
            Parameter validation failed
```

I think this error is due to endpoint URL of S3. We need to set localstack's S3 endpoint here in order to enable remote storage. But I am unable to get any help on google regarding this.

Please someone help me in this.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Having just set up remote storage on our live Magento 2.4.3 website following the documentation I had the same issue and like you, assumed it was an endpoint issue.

The missing part was actually a `-n` parameter on the end of the `php bin/magento setup:config:set` command.

If you view the documentation page [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage-aws-s3.html) the command listed at point number 4 of enabling remote storage includes this parameter:

`bin/magento setup:config:set --remote-storage-driver="aws-s3" --remote-storage-bucket="<bucket-name>" --remote-storage-region="<region-name>" --remote-storage-prefix="<optional-prefix>" --remote-storage-key=<optional-access-key> --remote-storage-secret=<optional-secret-key> -n`

If you view the documentation page [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage.html) however, on the "Enable remote storage" section, the parameter is missing:

`bin/magento setup:config:set --remote-storage-driver="aws-s3" --remote-storage-bucket="myBucket" --remote-storage-region="us-east-1"`

Answer (score 0):

Even though add -n parameter on the end of the php bin/magento setup:config:set command gives same error, anyone please let me know what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have LocalStack working successfully in my local environment. Here's my setup:

- Magento env - https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento
- LocalStack added to `docker-compose.yml` with

```
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-}
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - SKIP_SSL_CERT_DOWNLOAD=1
      - CUSTOM_SSL_CERT_PATH=/var/lib/localstack/custom/server.test.pem
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - ".ssl/server.includesprivatekey.pem:/var/lib/localstack/custom/server.test.pem"
      - "./conf/localstack/init:/etc/localstack/init"
      - "./conf/localstack/s3:/var/tmp/s3"
```

- nginx config -

```
...
location /media/ {
...
 location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
    # Proxying to AWS S3 storage.
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    set $bucket "test-local-s3";
    proxy_pass http://localstack:4566/$bucket$uri;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_pass_request_headers off;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_hide_header "x-amz-id-2";
    proxy_hide_header "x-amz-request-id";
    proxy_hide_header "x-amz-storage-class";
    proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
    proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
}
```

- in `env.php`

```
'remote_storage' => [
        'driver' => 'aws-s3',
        'config' => [
            'bucket' => 'test-local-s3',
            'bucket_endpoint' => false,
            'region' => 'east-1',
            'scheme' => 'http',
            'endpoint' => 'http://localstack:4566',
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => 'any-key-is-fine',
                'secret' => 'any-pw-is-fine',
            ],
            'debug' => true,

        ]
    ]
```